# Is there a way to see the compile times of each module?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghcjs

I've searched the ghc user manual to the best of my ability, but I haven't been able to find a way to have ghc print the timings of each module as it is compiled.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you've found `-ddump-timings` which dumps runtime in milliseconds by stage and module?  I'm pretty sure your best bet will be to parse its output and sum the times by module.

Looking through the GHC source, the only one piece of code that calls `getCPUTime` is in file `compiler/GHC/Utils/Error.hs`, function `withTiming'`, and this is the output that's enabled by `-ddump-timings`.  While there could technically be some call to `withTiming'` that accounts for the total compilation time of a module, it strikes me as unlikely that it would be disabled by default, and a search for all occurrences of `withTiming` in the compiler code base doesn't turn up anything.  So, the `-ddump-timings` output is probably the best you can do.

Comment: Yes, `-ddump-timings` seems to be the only option.   Thanks!